# ERROR: LoadError: No deps.jl file could be found. Please try running Pkg.build("Arpack")

Tags: julia

This the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61979936/cannot-convert-arrayany-2-to-series-data-for-plotting) of my first question from where get the following code

```
using DataFrames, IndexedTables, StatsPlots

df = DataFrame(a = 1:10, b = 10 .* rand(10), c = 10 .* rand(10))
@df df plot(:a, [:b :c], colour = [:red :blue])
```

In which while installing `StatsPlots` I got the following error `Error building 'Arpack'` which I ignore and then when I run above code I am getting the following error `ERROR: LoadError: No deps.jl file could be found. Please try running Pkg.build("Arpack").` so use `Pkg.build("Arpack")` which gives me the following error

```
 ┌ Error: Error building `Arpack`: 
 │ ERROR: LoadError: LibraryProduct(nothing, ["libarpack"], :libarpack, "Prefix(/home/anil/.julia/packages/Arpack/zCmTA/deps/usr)") is not satisfied, cannot generate deps.jl!
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

information about my system

```
julia> versioninfo()

Julia Version 1.0.4
Platform Info:
OS: Linux (x86_64-linux-gnu)
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4210U CPU @ 1.70GHz
WORD_SIZE: 64
LIBM: libopenlibm
LLVM: libLLVM-6.0.0 (ORCJIT, haswell)
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [Arpack.jl README](https://github.com/JuliaLinearAlgebra/Arpack.jl), you will have to compile [arpack-ng](https://github.com/opencollab/arpack-ng) binaries.

Here is the steps I followed on macOS 10.15.4 (should also work on Linux):

1. First download the [v3.5.0 release of arpack-ng](https://github.com/opencollab/arpack-ng/releases/tag/3.5.0) and extract to a folder.
2. Install `autoconf`, `automake` and `libtool` (here is an example using Anaconda, but you could also use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh), [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org), or `apt` in Linux):

```
conda install autoconf automake libtool
```

3. Install the [gfortran compiler](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries).
4. Go to the folder where you extracted `arpack-ng` in step 1 and follow the [build instructions](https://github.com/opencollab/arpack-ng):

```
sh bootstrap
./configure
make
make check
make install
```

5. Copy the compiled libs to your Julia packages folder:

```
sudo cp SRC/.libs/libarpack* ~/.julia/packages/Arpack/zCmTA/deps/usr/lib/
```

6. Run `Pkg.build("Arpack")` again.
7. Profit!